# ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, internationalization

I'm starting a new solution in ASP.NET MVC5 and I'll have to implement internationalization for the whole views.

The best article I found so far that explains how to well implement ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization was [this one](http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/). I also read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446321/global-resource-vs-local-resource-in-asp-net).

Anyway I still have some questions that I'd like the ask here in order to make sure about the best practices of internationalization which ones I still haven't found clearly answers on web.

1. Where should I put my **local** (resources for a specific view) .resx files?
   App_LocalResources folder? ItemView folder with all the other files? Where exactly and why?
2. How can I access my local resources values? Should I put them over the same App_GlobalResources namespace's .resx files (namespace Resources)?

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx), local resources are a concept relative to .aspx views.

In MVC, it is recommended to avoid **App_GlobalResources** and **App_LocalResources**. A great answer/explanation regarding this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926972/3669863).

Alternatives to App_*Resources include:

**Properties > Resources**

[image]

**Resources Folder**

[image]

**Resources Project**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your resource files in a custom folder.
I created a "resources" folder and it works like a charm.

[image: My project]

To access values, here an example for an action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Labels.Archivio, "Archivio", "Home")
```

Note you don't specify the Language, because MVC takes the locale loaded into the current thread

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```